# RARP REQUEST Is using broadcasting

Tags: networking

Why broadcast is happening in RARP request , we already know the sender and destination Mac address . Just send unicast request and get the Ip address..! What is the reason for using broadcasting...?

Answer (score 0):

The original reason is for a computer to discover its own IP address, and at the point of booting, the computer would not know the MAC address of any servers to help.